# Search and replace certain X,Y pairs in a set of X Y Z coordinates

Tags: excel, replace, find

I have a EXCEL table consisting of a list of 100 points with the coordinates X Y Z. I want to find and replace certain X and Y coordinates, not just the X coordinate.

For example in the picture below,

I want to find all the points in my table which have `X=1` , `Y=2` and replace with `X=9`, `Y=9` . Not just find `X=1` and replace with `X=9` Because is has to match both X and Y coordinates.

Comment: What have you try? Which picture?

Answer (score 0):

First, get your X+Y columns together . lets say your info is found on columns a+b then you can concatenate them together for d2 insert:

```
=a2&","&a3
```

Now drug it to the bottom of your data.

select column d and copy it then paste special on the same place with values.
After that you can just replace with simple replace ( ctrl+f) all the pairs you wish.
When you done, you can extract this back to 2 columns with date ribbon -> text to column (with delimiter.)